# Wrong Chrome top bar on Android with Flutter and InAppWebView

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, browser, flutter-inappwebview

**UPDATE: The problem was, that Samsung A53 has Samsung Internet as default browser. So the question is, how `ChromeSafariBrowser` can handle it? Is it possible to force open Chrome or is there an another workaround?**

On Samsung A53 (Android 13) using InAppWebView in Flutter, I am getting semi-transparent top bar in browser as well as a different lock icon, when opening a link with `ChromeSafariBrowser`.

[image: Wrong top bar on Samsung A53]

On other Android devices (Samsung S21 or Samsung S8 on Android 13) as well as on iOS it doesn't look semi-transparent and all navigation buttons look clear and good. It also should be like this:

[image: Right top bar on Samsung S21 and Samsung S8]

The code I am using to open a link in `ChromeSafariBrowser`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(value);
  ChromeSafariBrowser().open(
    url: uri,
    options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
      ios: IOSSafariOptions(
        barCollapsingEnabled: true,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

`initialOptions` for `InAppWebView`:

```
InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          supportZoom: false,
          disableContextMenu: true,
          verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
          horizontalScrollBarEnabled: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
        disableDefaultErrorPage: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        disallowOverScroll: false,
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures: false,
        allowsLinkPreview: false,
        disableLongPressContextMenuOnLinks: false,
      ));
```

What could be a reason for such behavior on Samsung A53?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChromeSafariBrowser` handles it like this with `packageName` set to `'com.android.chrome'`:

```
ChromeSafariBrowser().open(
          url,
          options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
            android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
              packageName: 'com.android.chrome',
            ),
            ios: IOSSafariOptions(
              barCollapsingEnabled: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
```